# PhpStorm view file transfer logs

Tags: intellij-idea, ftp, phpstorm, file-transfer

I use FTP deployment tool shipped with PhpStorm. When I transfer files, IDE shows process info, see image:

[image: file transfer log]

How to view this logs for particular date, for example, for 2 days ago? Does IDE stores file transfer logs via file or via some database?

Comment: IDE does not store this log anywhere: it lasts for current session only

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne. You may answer the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE does not store logs for a File Transfer toolwindow anywhere: they stay in that toolwindow for the duration of a session (or until toolwindow is fully closed).

Sadly, I do not know about possibility of telling IDE to store such log in some file.